# Dynamic type generation in TypeScript for an array of function callbacks

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have the following

```
class Logger {
 // logger class
}
const logger: Logger = new Logger();

// And a few scripts
const script1 = (log: Logger) => () => {
    log.info('running script1');
}
const script2 = (log: Logger) => (var1: string) => {
    log.info('running script2', var1);
}
```

I want to basically automatically inject the logger into each of these scripts; I have something like:

```
const injectLogger = (...scripts) => {
    return scripts.reduce((accum, script) => {
        accum[script.name] = script(logger);
        return accum;
    }, {});
}

const scripts = injectLogger(script1, script2);

// scripts.script1 and scripts.script2 are available for usage
```

This works well, however, the dynamic type definition is not - i.e. IDE does not understand `scripts.script1` exists or that `scripts.script2` requires a variable `var1` of type string.

How do I generate this dynamic type of definition? Can this even be done?

Comment: Where does `script.name` come from?

Comment: its the name of the function

Comment: You can't get what you want if you are dynamically passing in arbitrary `scripts` at runtime. The type checker needs to know at compile time what the possible values are.